# Unable to clone github library to python

Tags: python-3.x, git, github, pip

i trying to clone https://github.com/zhangchiyu10/pyC45 this repo to my python.

i was using 
`pip install git+https://github.com/zhangchiyu10/pyC45.git`

```
ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
  ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "c:\python37\lib\tokenize.py", line 447, in open
      buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\YULIAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-sqgmxgf8\\setup.py'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\YULIAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-sqgmxgf8\
```

any idea about how to use github library?

Comment: that's not really a "package" (i.e. it does not provide tools to install via pip like proper setup.py). just download pyC45.py into your working directory/project

Comment: @buran That should be an answer.

Comment: @phd, ok, I will post as answer

Answer (score 1):

that's not really a "package" (i.e. it does not provide tools to install via `pip` like proper `setup.py`). just download pyC45.py into your working directory/project